# Need help identifying an old bicycle, unusual frame

Tags: identify-this-bike

I was recently given a bicycle by an Italian restaurant, the owner had brought it back from Italy years ago and used it as wall decor. I have since replaced the chain, brake etc. However I am very curious as to how old it is, what it is, or any information. The decal says "Freyus" but when I search for it I can't find anything remotely similar to this bike. Does anyone know anything about it? I have done a web search and index search of the bike frames serial number and it has turned up nothing.

[image]
http://s23.postimg.org/l922ca617/image.jpg

Comment: Unrelated, but you might want to inspect that rear tire. Looks like it's coming unseated from the rim, which will lead to a tube blistering out on you at some point soon...

Answer (score 8):

Looks like a generic beach cruiser - not very old either.  The brazed lugs on the downtube suggest it was a geared bike, converted to single speed.

The V brakes say its no older than the 90s, and probably post-2000.

Its doesn't appear to be anything specifically Italian.  Still if it rides nicely, then ride it.   There's likely no museum or vintage nature there.

Comment: Thank you! Now I won't feel so bad about respraying it :)

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the above, I do know that Freyus (frejus) was a french vintage bicycle company that made very nice bikes at one point, however in the mid 80's they were sold to Bianchi, so if I had to guess, It is a new bicycle made by Bianchi but sold under the generic name Freyas as to not tarnish their name with an entry level product. Which would make sense judging by the color of the fenders and graphics, it looks similar to Bianchi's Celeste Green, just a little more bold and flashy

Answer (score 2):

The Freyus name in bikes has been around since 1896.  According to the following Italian Wiki page, Bianchi did purchase the name in the 70s, which had already morphed into "Frejus" (and while my Italian is.. almost non-existent, I'm pretty certain there's no change in pronunciation.)

Then, in 2006, the Masciaghi Brothers (Fratelli Masciaghi) bike company - who already had several brands under their domain - bought the rights to Frejus.

I would ask Bianchi if they can trace the serial, and if not, perhaps it was made under Fratelli Masciaghi.

The Wiki page:
[Frejus (company)](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frejus_%28azienda%29)

The Fratelli Masciaghi catalog page for Frejus (note the wreath and font combined with your head-badge and top-tube name):

[Masciaghi - Frejus](http://www.masciaghi.it/pagine_1.php?id=172)

Good luck!

Comment: Gidday and welcome to SE Bicycles.  Good answer - I look forward to your future contributions.